# From which version on will Hibernate support JPA 2.2?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.2

As Java EE 8 including JPA 2.2 was released this summer it's good to know when Hibernate will support it.
Hibernate 5.2 is mentioned to support JPA 2.1. Hibernate 6.0 roadmap doesn't have any references to JPA 2.2 support.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old(ish) question, but according to their [website](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.3/) the 5.3 "series" will support JPA 2.2. However, as of the posting of this answer it seems the 5.2 series is still the latest stable release.

---

**Update (June 8, 2018)**

As helpfully mentioned by MWiesner in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50749097/6395627), the Hibernate 5.3 series has been released and supports JPA 2.2. It was released on May 14, 2018 and version 5.3.1 has already been released as well (on May 28, 2018).

Answer (score 6):

With the recent Hibernate release of [version 5.3](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.3/) in May 2018, JPA 2.2 is now fully supported:

> Hibernate 5.3 adds support for the **JPA 2.2** specification

For reference, find further details in the official [Hibernate ORM 5.3 migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.3/migration-guide.adoc).